# Why does my android phone gain battery when I turn it off and on again?

Tags: battery-life

When I got my new android phone (ZTE N762), I noticed something. If my phone is about halfway on battery, and I turn it off for a few hours, it will gain battery life when I turn it back on, around 5%-10%. I use this trick whenever I'm low on battery.

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt very much that your battery is actually gaining energy, what with the conservation of energy and all that.  Instead I imagine that the meter is fairly inaccurate, and is inaccurate in a different way just after you turn on the phone, than when the phone has been running a while.